# update mysql table with list values

Tags: php

i have a form that extract data from mysql table into a form, each row has a menu to choose a value from and i want to update mysql with each value choosen for each row when the 'Apply To All' button is clicked but doesnt work at all.,here is my code.

```
<td><form id="main" name="main" method="post" action="setProjectStatus.php" onsubmit="return validateMain();">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
          <td width="35%" rowspan="3"><img src="../img/project.jpg" alt="Comp Sci Stud" width="325" height="199" border="2" /></td>
          <td width="65%" height="42" colspan="2"><table width="94%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="main_table">
            <tr class="table_title">
              <td width="100%" class="table_title">Set Project Status. </td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="26">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="26"><table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                <tr class="table_head">
                  <td width="2%" height="35"><div align="center"></div></td>
                  <td width="26%" height="35"><div align="center">Student Name</div></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><div align="center">Project</div></td>
                  <td width="19%"><div align="center">Status</div></td>
                </tr>
<?php
 session_start();
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];

 require_once("mysqlConnect.php"); 

//
$sql="SELECT * FROM spms_Student";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "There are $count projects to be undertaken.";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//
$query = "SELECT name FROM spms_systemUser WHERE userId = '".$rows[0]."'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$name = $row[0];
?>

                <tr>
                  <td height="25" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="center"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                  <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $rows[1]; ?></td>
                  <td align="center"><label>
                    <select name="select" class="form_field_100px_select">
                      <option value="Pending" selected="selected">Pending</option>
                      <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
                      <option value="Disapproved">Disapproved</option>
                    </select>
                  </label></td>
                </tr>
<?php
}
?>
                <tr class="pager_bg">
                  <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td width="37%" align="right"><input name="done" type="button" id="done" value="Done" onclick="window.location='../coordinatorMenu.html'" /></td>
                  <td width="16%"><label>
                    <input name="approveAll" type="submit" id="approveAll" value="Approve All" />
                  </label></td>
                  <td><input name="apply" type="submit" id="apply" value="Apply To All" /></td>
                </tr>
<?php
mysql_close();
?>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><label></label>            <label></label></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form></td>
```

Comment: and what is the code in setProjectStatus.php?

Comment: That would help alot.. We can't really help you with this since it seems all the magic is happening on the other page ;)

Comment: this page is calling itself,,and only this code at the top...                                                            if (isset($_POST['approveAll'])) {

 //connect and choose a database
 require_once("mysqlConnect.php");
 
 $sql = "UPDATE tablename SET projectStatus = 'Approved'";
 mysql_query($sql);
}

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reuse your MySQL connection while still holding on to the resultset from the first query. You need to create a second connection for the inner loop queries. Even better would probably be to rewrite your query using a join, but I can't say for sure without knowing your schema.